# Reformat how a number is displayed in a line of text file with sed

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal

I have a text file that has several lines and I am looking to replace lines that are formatted like:

```
cat: -0600, dog: +0900
cat: -1000, snake: -0500
cat: -0900
cat: +0100
```

to say

```
cat: -6, dog: +0900
cat: -10, snake: -0500
cat: -9
cat: +1
```

there are other lines that are:

```
dog: -0700
dog: +1000
```

that shouldn't be touched. I've searched, can't quite figure it out. Prefer to use sed, unless there's better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your composite data file, this script gives the sample output below:

```
sed 's/^\(cat: [-+]\)0\{0,1\}\([1-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]\)00/\1\2/' data
```

It looks for `cat:` followed by a `+` or `-`, then an optional 0 (which is not captured), then an optional `[1-9]` followed `[0-9]` followed by two `0`'s, and replaces that with the two remembered parts.  It would convert `+0000` to `+0`.  If the last two digits are not always `00`, modify the first regex to match `[0-5][0-9]` or `[0-9][0-9]`.

Sample output:

```
cat: -6, dog: +0900
cat: -10, snake: -0500
cat: -9
cat: +1
dog: -0700
dog: +1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Two expressions should make that work:

`sed 's|^cat: -0600|cat: -6|; s|^dog: -0700|dog: -7|;' file`

Comment: dog lines **that shouldn't be touched.**

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with awk, I don't know if you think it is a **better** way:

```
awk '/^cat: /{$2/=100}7' file
```

test with your input:

```
kent$  echo "cat: -0600
cat: -1000
cat: -0900
cat: +0100
dog: -0700
dog: +1000"|awk '/^cat: /{$2/=100}7'
cat: -6
cat: -10
cat: -9
cat: 1
dog: -0700
dog: +1000
```

**if you really want to have a plus "`+`" before the positive numbers:**

```
awk '/^cat: /{$2/=100;$2=$2>0?"+"$2:$2}7' file
```

same input:

```
kent$  echo "cat: -0600
cat: -1000
cat: -0900
cat: +0100
dog: -0700
dog: +1000"|awk '/^cat: /{$2/=100;$2=$2>0?"+"$2:$2}7'
cat: -6
cat: -10
cat: -9
cat: +1
dog: -0700
dog: +1000
```

Comment: it's close, but it seems that if cat: -0700 is on the same line as anything else, then it doesnt work. if cat: -0700 is on its own line by itself it does.

Comment: Note that this answer was written before the sample data was changed to include `dog` and `snake` after the `cat` entries on the first two lines.  This should not be held against it.